# Unable to access jarfile 'tabula-1.0.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar'

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller

I made a python executable using pyinstaller as `pyinstaller --onefile script.py`. When I run the script.exe, I get the following errors:

[image]

I am using tabula-py package to parse a pdf table. Script has no bugs though and is running pefect. Thanks!

Comment: Please don't post code or stacktraces as images. Use markdown code formatting and add them to your answer.

Answer (score 10):

This problem is apparently caused because the above mentioned jar file is not added to the `dist` folder structure properly.

I guess a fundamental solution would require some modifications from the side of the developers, but a possible workaround here is to use the option `--add-data` option to include the jar file into a folder called *tabula*, so something like

```
pyinstaller --add-data path:\to\tabula-(...).jar; tabula
```

in order to make it run, or set something like

```
datas=[('path:\to\tabula-(...).jar', 'tabula')],
```

into the spec file. Made both regular builds and one-file-builds runnable for me.

Comment: Great failtrolol. I had success copying tabula-1.0.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar to the script folder and entering pyinstaller --add-data tabula-1.0.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar;tabula --onefile Pdf2Excel.py

Comment: See https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/5298